# How to define if NotificationChannel was disabled by user (API 26)?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

I updated my code to API v26, set up NotificationChannels and I can see my notifications, but I have logic regarding disabled notifications.
Before 26 I have something like:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

And this seems to be not useful now. So how can one know if notification channel is disabled in the settings?

Comment: Maybe notification channel's [importance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#getImportance()) becomes [IMPORTANCE_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_NONE)? I'm not sure, just assuming.

Comment: @azizbekian thank you for the assumption, it turns that you are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that new **`ChannelNotification`** approach doesn't replace old logic, it adds one more layer of control for notifications.
So now we have 2 scenarios, see Screenshot:

[image]

1. You can define if notifications enabled:

   ```
     NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();
   ```
2. You can define if your notification is visible to user:

   ```
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
     context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);       
     NotificationChannel notificationChannel = 
     notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);      
     int importance = notificationChannel.getImportance();
   ```

If importance is `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE` user will not see notification, but the notification is there, so you can use it with Foreground service and you should dismiss it. If importance is `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN` or higher user will see notification.